# Excel doesn't replace 7 for 07 in a formated text cell

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office

Excel doesn't display the zero at the beginning of the text cell.
This file must be in a specific format for a program to read it, so it's very important that the cell is set as text.

THE CELL MUST BE SET AS TEXT, IT CANNOT BE CODE OR CUSTOM it's for a program to read and not a human, the formating is important.

IMPORTANT: I can't add any new data/collumn/row/code to my file, the program that reads it requires it to be a set number of collumn and doesn't read code.

Here is the cell set as text:

[image: Cell set as text]

Here is how I'm tryng to replace it:

[image: tryng to replace]

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is right click the cells you want to change, click "Format Cells", then on the Number tab click the "Custom" list option. The field under "Type:" will allow you to format text in the same way the second half of my answer does. 00 will allow one preceding zero for single digit numbers and no preceding zeroes for two digit numbers:

[image: Setting cell format using the format cells dialog box]

Alternatively, you can also do the following as you seem to have multiple rows using the same data:

[image: Setting cell format using a function]

The [TEXT function](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx) `=Text(CELL, "XXXX")` allows you to set preceding zeroes depending on how many digits are in the row it references, among other things.

Comment: As i said it's very important that i is infact saving 07 as a text, it cannot be just the number with a diferent formating, what you have show just add a 0 zero in the view port, doesn't add it to the file

Comment: @JayttCorrea Doing it either of the ways I mentioned still saves the numbers as text, and they have the preceding value when viewed in the csv format, the most likely way you'd read values in from an excel file.

Comment: Using =Text(CELL, "XXXX") is not viable, i have a file with more than 10,000 items, but i sure both ways you showed aren't right because it is aligned at the right and has no warnings

Comment: I found a way to do it with an axiliar software, but i realy want to do it on excel direcly, it would be easier to me

Comment: Use the cell format option I gave you and not the function one. It works, you just have to apply it to all the cells you want to have the format. Like I said, exporting to csv shows that the zeroes are there, your program will process them. You would click on "Personalizado" and type 00 in the text box under "Tipo".

Comment: Formatting as you suggest won't change the value stored by Excel, it will still be a number, even if displayed as `07`. The only way to store it as text is to force Excel to do it, either by using a formula, either by using a `'`.

Comment: i doesn't... Man, i'm a programer not a noob, do you realy think i didn't try this obvius staff? As I said, it only looks like it has a zero, it's not save to the file, and i REALY NEED it to be a  set as TEXT.

Comment: `=TEXT(cell,"00")` creates a text field: this appears to be what you say you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enter a number as text in Excel, you can do it by adding a single quote (<kbd>'</kbd>) in front of the number, e.g. `'07`. This will force Excel to store as text, even if it looks like a number.

As quicker alternative, if you have lots of values, you can use a temporary column with the formula `="0"&V3` or `=""&V3`. Copy this cell and paste it in values in the column V, and Excel will store it as a text.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a work around, i copied the collum to notepad++ and edited it there, then i copied it back to excel, it works, but it's not ideal, please if you have a way to make it without an axiliar software it would be much better

Comment: It is not at all clear what your real question is. How are you reading the Excel file? What is wrong with the two solutions in [Dispenser](https://superuser.com/users/327653/dispenser)'s answer? Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? You need to expand your question to tell us more.

Comment: I'm using a program to upload the excel data to a data base, this program requires that all fields must be text/strings/varchar, if you just make a costum formating the zero will appear on the view port but the file will continue to be save as a number, i don't want it to look like it has a zero, i want it to really have this zero and save it o the file

Comment: Also i can add any new collum, it's for me to read, it's for a program

Comment: So this may be a problem with the data-base import, not the Excel export?

Comment: Nope, it works when i do what i said in this answer. The problem is that the excel doesn't save it as text

Comment: You haven't given enough information: none of of the suggested solutions conflicts with what you say you want. What do you do in Notepad++? How do you you export to the database? What database? What do you mean that Excel doesn't save it as text? How is it saved? How do you want it saved? You must clarify your requirements.

Comment: to fix it with notepade++ i just copy the collum into it and do a find and replace then i copy it back. Try it, you will see the diference, no need for my exporter.

Comment: What do you find? What do you replace it with?

Comment: yep, i just replace it, but as i said, it's not ideal, i would prefer a internal tool of excel

Answer (score -1):

Try this in adjacent cell & fill down.

[image]

```
 =REPT(0,2-LEN(A2))&A2
```

**NB:** Suppose you want 2 leading zero before numbers then **replace 2 with 3** in the Formula values will looks like shown below.

```
007
008
005
002
006
```

Comment: the order, name and quantities of column can not be change, i cant add any new collumn

Comment: Then better you select the column & apply the Custom Format ,,as shown below by Dispenser,because if you want the value to SET AS TEXT,  another column is required to use Text Function. but always remember number should not be formatted  as Text ,,, logically it's wrong in context of calculations even though Excel undermine it  :-)

Comment: So, the only solution is to use some axiliar tool... Sadly excel can't save a string that contains only number as starts with a 0 by it self. I'm using excel only to organize data, i don't need it to anything else.